# Help needed to restore my Google Nexus 7 to a working state

Tags: nexus-7

I attempted to flash the factory image for Android 4.4.4 on my Google Nexus 7 (2012), but it wasn't successful. This now resulted in my device no longer booting up, I am also unable to get into fast boot mode, or recovery mode.  When I plug my device into my computer, it shows as an unrecognised device.

What can I do to restore my Nexus to a fully working state?

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3342364